# Django - запрос к базе данных DateTimeField

Tags: mysql, python, django

Задача такая - как можно построить запрос, чтобы выбирать все записи где разница между текущим временем и временем записи была не больше одно часа или одно дня (24 часов)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
time_threshold = now - timedelta(hours=1) # или days=1
results = YourModel.objects.filter(
    created__gt=time_threshold,
    created__lte=now)
```

Постфикс `__gt` в фильтре означает "greater than".
`__lte` соответственно - "less than or equal".

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#gt).